# how to check presence of debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, syntax

Is there a possibility to check the presence of the `debugger`-statement provided by Google Chrome?

Tried to put it into a **simple if**

`if(debugger) ...`

and the **or-shorthand**

`debugger || doSth();`

but both trigger a syntax error.

Comment: `debugger` has been supported since ECMAScript 1 and is present in all browsers. you are safe to just use it without checking.

Comment: well, i wasn't aware of that. thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: because if the user of our _service_ manages to write an infinite loop, there should be a pretty way to debug it, instead of just breaking the loops.